# pandas groupby not working for 3 columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to calculate Sum of column d in group by result of column a,b,c.

Although I have 2 different values in column c but still it is not coming as part of same group resulting sum is not calculated properly.

Please suggest.
Code I am using is :

```
s  = df.groupby(['a','b','c'])['d'].sum()

a    b    c    d

1    ab  123   1

1    ab  123   2
```

Output should be :

```
1    ab  123   3
```

But output is coming as

```
1    ab  123   1

         123   2
```

df.dtypes

a int64

b object

c object

d float64

Comment: This definitely needs a [mcve]

Comment: Somehow it is taking time to add that from mobile but I am doing it

Comment: You would need to add the dataframe example for which you are getting the issue

Comment: Now your example might be minimal, but it is not complete or verifiable. Include some example input and output, with both the expected output as well as the output you're getting.

Comment: You need to show raw input data, code that creates your df, the groupby and the desired result and why your above code doesn't give you what you want, we can't guess from your description why it's wrong

Comment: I reproduced your example, and got right outcome, as expected. `df.groupby(['a','b','c']).sum()['d']` and `df.groupby(['a','b','c'])['d'].sum()` both give a single row

`1  ab  123    3`

Comment: @Vipin check if there is some small difference between both `c` values, maybe its of type string and they have spaces or something. How are you creating the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After changing datatype of column c from object to int and it worked.

Now b is still object , so looking for why it is working after changing c only.